# Modifying contents of location path in web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, authorization, restrictions

I have a small problem trying to modify my Web.config from code. All I'm trying to do is access my authorization rules and add a bunch, which will be later useful for any administrator of the page. However, I have no idea how to get past   - the piece of code that keeps everything together, restricting access to the folder.

Here is the Web.config part:

```
 <location path="Admin" >

<system.web >
  <authorization>

    <allow roles="Administrator, Superadministrator" />

    <deny users="*"/>

  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

And here is the code:

```
var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
        var section = (AuthorizationSection)configuration.GetSection("system.web/authorization");
        var info3 = section.Rules[0].Roles.ToString();
        section.Rules[0].Roles.Add("Ultraadministrator");
        var info33 = section.Rules[0].Roles.ToString();
        Label1.Text = info33;
        configuration.Save();
```

The problem is in the GetSection part, I'd like to the location, but I have no idea how to. Can anyone help?